# Problems with register PHP/MySQL form code

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I'm having problems with a simple register form:

```
<form  method="post" action="register.php">

    Username: <input type="text" name="field_register_username">
    Password: <input type="password" name="field_register_password"> 
    Confirm Password: <input type="password" name="field_register_password_confirm">

<input class="button_01" type="sumbit" value="Register" name="register_button">

</form>
```

register.php

```
<?php

    if($_POST){

        $r_username = isset($_POST['field_register_username'])?$_POST['field_register_username']:"";
        $r_password =   isset($_POST['field_register_password'])?$_POST['field_register_password']:"";
        $r_confirm =    isset($_POST['field_register_password_confirm'])?$_POST['field_register_password_confirm']:"";

        if(!empty($r_username) && !empty($r_password)){

            if($r_password != $r_confirm){/*ERRORMSG=PASSWORDSDONTMATCH*/}

            else{

                require 'config.php';

                $db_connection = mysql_connect($db_host,$db_username,$db_password) or die(mysql_error());

                mysql_select_db($db_name,$db_connection);

                $query = sprintf("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users WHERE UPPER(username) = UPPER('%s')", mysql_real_escape_string($r_username));

                $query_result = mysql_query($query);

                if($query_result != 0){/*ERRORMSG=ACCOUNTALREADYEXISTS*/}

                $query = sprintf("INSERT INTO users(username,password,auth) VALUES ('%s','%s','%d')", mysql_real_escape_string($username), mysql_real_escape_string(md5($r_password)), 1);

                mysql_query($query);
            }

        }

        else {/*ERRORMSG=BLANKFIELD*/}

    }

?>
```

When I submit the form it seems that the action is never done or even start. I suspect that there is a problem with the first `isset var` declarations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you gave a typo in html input type submit, change:

```
<input class="button_01" type="sumbit" value="Register" name="register_button">
```

to

```
<input class="button_01" type="submit" value="Register" name="register_button">
```

its `submit` not `sumbit`